# Why Control Center is constantly taking ~40% CPU?

Tags: control-center

I'm an engineer who needs to work in outdoor environment with my Intel Macbook Pro. I realized that even I minimize energy consumption from apps I installed, the Control Center still constantly consumes 40% of CPU even nothing is going on.

Why does Control Center needs CPU at spare time? Is there a way to disable Control Center? or minimize its workload to make CPU low enough?

[attached my sampling: https://pastebin.com/baqS3LjP on Monterey 12.3.1]

Comment: Can we assume you are seeing 40% CPU use by Control Center/Centre process in Activity Monitor? If so your question might be better put as "Why does Control Centre use 40% CPU" rather than disabling it (which I suspect is not possible).

Comment: Just running Activity Monitor now and Control Centre is not even on the list. Firefox is using 26% though

Comment: thanks, both. yes I'm referring to numbers in activity monitor. that might worth dig deeper what Control Center is actually doing in such ~40% moments, if in Solar's case it's so ignorable.